# Remove rows where column exists in select statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to delete rows who specific column exists in select statement like:

```
delete from [ProjectCustomer] pcc 
where ProjectKey in (
  select p.ProjectKey  
  FROM [Project] AS [p] inner JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [pd] ON [p].[ProjectKey] = [pd].[ProjectKey]
  inner JOIN [Design] AS [d] ON [pd].[DesignKey] = [d].[DesignKey]
  inner JOIN [ProjectCustomer] AS [pc] ON [pc].[ProjectKey] = [p].[ProjectKey]
  inner join Customer as c on pc.CustomerKey = c.CustomerKey
  where d.Folio = 3014)
```

But in where clause of delete statement I get

> Incorrect syntax near where clause

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: Could you please add enough of the database schema for the above query to refer to existing table and column names? It might help me diagnose your issue.

Comment: Should be `delete pcc from [ProjectCustomer] pcc`

Comment: try removing pcc alias as you are not using it.

Answer (score 1):

DELETE statement with table alias has different syntax, so either you can remove the alias as it's unused or change the delete statement like @Martin commented.

```
delete pcc from [ProjectCustomer] pcc
```

I would preper to revise the query using `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN`

```
delete pcc from [ProjectCustomer] AS pcc 
  inner join [Project] AS [p] ON [p].ProjectKey = [pcc].ProjectKey
  inner JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [pd] ON [p].[ProjectKey] = [pd].[ProjectKey]
  inner JOIN [Design] AS [d] ON [pd].[DesignKey] = [d].[DesignKey]
  inner JOIN [ProjectCustomer] AS [pc] ON [pc].[ProjectKey] = [p].[ProjectKey]
  inner join Customer as c on pc.CustomerKey = c.CustomerKey
  where d.Folio = 3014)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message is

> Incorrect syntax near 'pcc'

instead of

> Incorrect syntax near where clause

You wil get the first error message cause you are using the alias wrong, so while you are not joining the target table, you may want

```
delete from [ProjectCustomer]
where ProjectKey in (
  select p.ProjectKey  
  FROM [Project] AS [p] inner JOIN [ProjectDesign] AS [pd] ON [p].[ProjectKey] = [pd].[ProjectKey]
  inner JOIN [Design] AS [d] ON [pd].[DesignKey] = [d].[DesignKey]
  inner JOIN [ProjectCustomer] AS [pc] ON [pc].[ProjectKey] = [p].[ProjectKey]
  inner join Customer as c on pc.CustomerKey = c.CustomerKey
  where d.Folio = 3014);
```

or even if you still want to use an alias

```
delete pcc from [ProjectCustomer] pcc
where pcc.ProjectKey in ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probably simplify your query a little. I think that you don't need a subquery, you can specify the table to delete from in the first FROM clause (without an alias) and join the tables in a second (using aliases as you like):

```
DELETE FROM ProjectCustomer
FROM ProjectCustomer pc
  INNER JOIN ProjectDesign pd ON pc.ProjectKey = pd.ProjectKey
    INNER JOIN Design d ON pd.DesignKey = d.DesignKey
WHERE d.Folio = 3014;
```

The `Customers` and `Products` table should not be neccessary, as long as you have set up referential integrity and `pc.CustomerKey` isn't nullable.